# h:commandButton action redirect to context root, possible?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

**Project context**

I've created from scratch an URL rewriting with two major component :

```
public class URLFilter implements Filter
{
    ...
}

public class URLViewHandler extends GlobalResourcesViewHandler
{
    ...
}
```

The first class is used to forward *clean* URLs to the right view with an ID different for each page. The second class override the function `getActionURL()` so that `h:form`  and ajax functionnalities continues to work.

Theses classes translate like this :

```
Real URL                 Internal URL
/                    <-> page.jspx?key=1
/contact             <-> page.jspx?key=2
/projects/management <-> page.jspx?key=3
etc
```

**Current solution**

My problem right now is for my user login and logout button :

```
<!-- Login button used if user is not logged, go to a secured page (which display error message). If he log with this button, the current page is reloaded and displayed properly. This button works perfectly -->
<h:commandButton rendered="#{pageActions.item.isPrivate}" value="#{msg.button_connect}" actionListener="#{userActions.onButtonLoginClick}" />
<!-- Login button used anywhere on public pages that redirect to user home after login, works perfectly since I haven't changed to clear url. -->
<h:commandButton rendered="#{not pageActions.item.isPrivate}" value="#{msg.button_connect}" actionListener="#{userActions.onButtonLoginClick}" action="userHome.jspx?faces-redirect=true" />
<!-- Logout button that works (it redirects at http://website.com/context-name/ but keep the ?key=1 at the end. -->
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.button_disconnect}" actionListener="#{userActions.onButtonLogoutClick}" action="page.jspx?key=1&amp;faces-redirect=true" styleClass="button" style="margin-left: 5px;" />
```

**My whishes**

My question : Is there a better way to program the logout button since I need to redirect to context-root, currently I'm using the view name with the home page key but I would prefer 1. using a real path 2. not keep the ?key=1 at the url.

Thank you!

**Final code**

Based on BalusC answer, here is my final code to share to others :

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class NavigationActions
{
    public void redirectTo(String p_sPath) throws IOException
    {
        ExternalContext oContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        oContext.redirect(oContext.getRequestContextPath() + p_sPath);
    }
}

<h:commandButton rendered="#{not pageActions.item.isPrivate}" value="#{msg.button_connect}" actionListener="#{userActions.onButtonLoginClick}" action="#{navigationActions.redirectTo(userSession.language.code eq 'fr' ? '/profil/accueil' : '/profile/home')}" />
```

Since I don't need the key when I have the path, it is even more better, thank you again BalusC to put me on the right track! Sent a small donation :)

Comment: I don't understand you question/problem. Have you tried navigation in faces-config.xml? <navigation-case>
   <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
   <to-view-id>/</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>

Comment: @roel, Thank you for the suggestion, I've tested and it is not working. The main concern is "how to put real url in buttons actions". I would like to put action="/" but it is not working. Also I don't want to use navigation rules.

Comment: By the way, why reinventing an URL rewriting solution instead of reusing an existing library like PrettyFaces for that?

Comment: Just because all pages & articles are in database!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't possible with (implicit) navigation. The `/` is unfortunately not a valid JSF view ID.

Use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) instead. Replace

```
action="page.jspx?key=1&amp;faces-redirect=true"
```

by

```
action="#{userActions.redirectToRootWithKey(1)}"
```

with

```
public void redirectToRootWithKey(int key) throws IOException {
    ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "?key=" + key);
}
```

Comment: Very nice, the exact solution to close the loop with my CMS! Thank you!

Comment: P.S.: Missing a parenthesis at the end of ec.redirect... :)

Comment: Hope there is a BalusC of Hibernate for my other question!